Folder inaccessible from dired after renaming
I am using a Windows 11 machine with WSL2 and Emacs is running through WSL2. The folder in question is on the Windows part (and not Linux partition) if it matters.
I renamed a folder in dired+ and now cannot access the folder. "newfolder" is the new name so the renaming was successful, but now permissions are unknown as shown below (which is the line for the folder in dired+) and I cannot open the directory through Emacs.
d????????? ? ?         ?            ?            ? newfolder

If I try to open the directory through find-file, I get the following message:
Listing directory failed but ‘access-file’ worked
and cannot view its contents. However, in Windows File Explorer, everything seems to be normal with the folder renamed as "newfolder".
Any ideas what is going on and if it is fixable?

Can you see the content of the directory by using plain ls newfolder/ in WSL2 terminal?

See if you can reproduce the problem when starting Emacs with emacs -Q (no init file), and without loading dired+.el. If so, try to present a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem (from emacs -Q).

@Hi-Angel yes good point - seemed fine on the WSL2 end.

@Drew After about 30 minutes the problem seemed to go away and I could access the directory so I could not reproduce it. Next time I would try this.

When you tested ls newfolder, was the problem with Emacs already gone or was it still there?

I’m voting to close this question because OP can't repro the problem.
